# Microsoft dynamics Mediaset Datatype and SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, sql-server-2016, ssrs-2016, navision

I have a table called Item in Microsot Dynamics (NAV).

One of the requirement is to display a picture that is attached to the item.

The SQL datatype of this field is "uniqueidentifier".

However, when looking at the development environment for dynamics, I see the following:

[image: MediaSet]

How do I retrieve and show this image in an SSRS report please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any one looking at this.  Navision Dynamics stores images as Mediasets.

These references are stored in the *[Tenant Media Set]* table and the actual image is in the *[Tenant Media Thumbnails]* table.

The images are stored as a BLOB . To be able to display these in an SSRS report, you need to ensure that the  Compression is set to NO on the field that holds the image. Field name is [*Content*]

Here is the SQL Query :

```
SELECT  ID, [Media ID], [Content], [Mime Type], Height, Width
FROM  [Tenant Media Thumbnails]
```

You can them simply display this field in the report by applying the following properties to an Image

[image]