# How to Display BLOB images from Dynamics (running on SQL Server 2016) in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, image, reporting-services, dynamics-crm, blob

I currently have a Navision Dynamics installation on SQL Server 2016.

I have a requirement to display pictues from Navision Dynamics CRM on a stand alone installation of SQL server reporting services (SSRS).

This means, I do not have any of the CRM functionality available for me to use.

The Data Sets for the report is standard SQL queries.

My test query and result :

[image]

The field Content from my above query is what I want to display as the image on the report.

If I look at the SQL datatype for the Content column, it says it is an Image (data type).

However, in dynamics, it is a data type of BLOB

[image]

I have tried to do this in the report and I just get a Red Cross (X):

[image]

I have also tried the following for this field and still get the red X :

```
=System.Convert.ToBase64String(Fields!Content.Value)
```

How do I go about displaying the Content field as an Image in the report please?

Comment: Fields!Content.Value isn't a base64 field?

Comment: @Sxntk how can I determine what it is?

Comment: copy and paste the content here: https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter#

Comment: Thanks.. it doesn't appear to be base64 unfortunately. Any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911460/blob-to-string-sql-server

Comment: Great.. not sure how I didn't come across that one! thanks. I have asked our developers to change the compression on the field and then I can test. I'll keep you posted!

Comment: @Sxntk Uncompressing the BLOB field and simply displaying it straight without any conversion worked like a charm for me. Thank you for the pointer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See answer in this post below :

[Microsoft dynamics Mediaset Datatype and SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65316289/microsoft-dynamics-mediaset-datatype-and-ssrs)

The questions is same / similar to this one.

The answer is - Change the image compression on the BLOB field to OFF and then everything else should work like in the question.